# Python + Pygame; screen.fill() crashing window

Tags: python, background, pygame, screen, fill

Whenever I try to include "screen.fill(insert value here)" to my pygame code, the window instantly crashes. I can comment it out and my code works just fine. I'm really not sure why.

I've tried moving the line around, using other people's code in part - no luck.

```py
import pygame
pygame.init()

win = pygame.display.set_mode((1000, 800))
pygame.display.set_caption("Tetris")

img=pygame.image.load("C:\\Users\\Charlotte\\Desktop\\tetris_grid.png")
win.blit(img,(450, 150))

running = True
while running:
    screen.fill(0, 0, 0)
    pygame.display.update()
    pygame.time.delay(100)

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            run = False

pygame.quit()
```

When I run the code with that line in it, the window opens and then it instantly closes.

Comment: No errors in the console? BTW, your loop will never end because you ask for `running` in the while loop and you change `run`. I wouldn't call that "works fine".

Comment: No, none.
At this point, this code is simply to display an image in pygame, and it does just that. It's the very beginning of my program, not a working game.

Comment: you should run it in console/terminal/cmd.exe - like `python script.py` - to see errors.

Comment: Did you initialize `screen`?

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to fill the screen with black, the color must be passed as a tuple:

```
win.fill((0, 0, 0))
```

Also, you never assign `screen`, maybe you intended to use `win`?

The doc for [Surface.fill](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/surface.html#pygame.Surface.fill).

Comment: I've tried it that way too, with the double brackets, no luck.
I'm not trying to turn it black, that's just a placeholder value from trying numerous values - I'm trying to turn it white.

Comment: Well, you never assign `screen`, try with `win`. (updated answer)

Comment: That's a start. It runs, but I can't see any images I put in anymore.

Comment: Are you using macOS and pygame 1.9? You might be having this issue: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56319838/pygame-does-not-fill-surface-or-blit-image-on-display-update . And here some workarounds: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52718921/problems-getting-pygame-to-show-anything-but-a-blank-screen-on-macos-mojave

Comment: @Charlotte You're not blitting the images in your example; you're only loading them into memory

Answer (score 1):

The color parameter to  [`fill()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/surface.html#pygame.Surface.fill) has to be either a single grayscale value or a tuple of 3 RGB or 4 RGBA components. So it has to be either:

```py
win.fill(0)
```

or

```py
win.fill((0, 0, 0))
```

Further you've to [`blit()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/surface.html#pygame.Surface.blit) the image in the main loop. To continuously draw the scene in the main application loop, you've to:

- handle the events
- clear the  window
- draw the scene (blit the image)
- update the display

Furthermore I recommend to use [`tick()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/time.html#pygame.time.Clock.tick) of  [`pygame.time.Clock`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/time.html#pygame.time.Clock) rather than [`pygame.time.delay()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/time.html#pygame.time.delay) tpo control the frames per second.

```py
import pygame

pygame.init()

win = pygame.display.set_mode((1000, 800))
pygame.display.set_caption("Tetris")
clock = pygame.time.Clock()

img=pygame.image.load("C:\\Users\\Charlotte\\Desktop\\tetris_grid.png")

running = True
while running:

    clock.tick(60)

    # handle the events
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            running = False

    # clear the display
    win.fill(0)

    # draw the scene
    win.blit(img,(450, 150))

    # update the display
    pygame.display.update()

pygame.quit()
```