# Pygame displaying blank white window

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame, pycharm, atom-editor

When running this code, i don't get any error but my window doesn't display anything except the name of the window, why? It doesn't work in Atom editor nor PyCharm.
EDIT: I'm using a mac

```
import pygame as pg

pg.init()

window = pg.display.set_mode((400, 300))
name = pg.display.set_caption('Hello World!')

white = (255, 255, 255)
green = (0, 255, 0)
blue = (0, 0, 128)

run = True

while run: # Main game loop
    pg.draw.rect(window, green, (0, 0, 50, 50))
    for event in pg.event.get():
        if event.type == pg.QUIT:
            run = False

    pg.display.flip()
```

Comment: Have you tried running it from command line? does it run then?

Comment: @Axe319 on my pycharm i get proper green rectangle displayed

Comment: @Axe319 Yes I've tried it but I still get the same result

Comment: Might be related to: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52718921/problems-getting-pygame-to-show-anything-but-a-blank-screen-on-macos-mojave

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it by:

1. Changing my Virtual environment to Anaconda 3 in atom
2. Opening jupyter notebook in anaconda and installed pygame using pip
3. Returned to Atom and ran the code again, the output was correct

I didn't have a selected virtual env on my project before so I'm sure it works by having any other virt-env as well. Thanks for the responses anyways.