# PyGame Window not starting

Tags: python, pygame, 2d-games, pygame-surface

I created this simple snake game a while ago and I wanted to try running it and for some reason the window is not starting on my machine. I am sure the code was working before. I tried debugging for a while but can't seem to figure out why I am stuck on a black screen. It seems to detect a key pressed but nothing is displayed on the screen.

```
import pygame
from pygame.locals import *
import random

# Global Color Variables
RED = (255, 0, 0)
WHITE = (255, 255, 255)
BLACK = (0, 0, 0)
CYAN = (0,255, 255)

# Set the speed of the Snake --> lower = faster
timeDelaySpeed = 0

class App:
    def __init__(self):
        self._running = True
        self._display_surf = None
        self.size = self.weight, self.height = 600, 700

        # create the boarder
        self.boarder = self.generateBoard()

        # Initial Snake array with 3 Snake Blocks starting at (50, 50) and going left
        self.snake = [Snake(WHITE, 10, 10, 150, 260), Snake(WHITE, 10, 10, 140, 260), Snake(WHITE, 10, 10, 130, 260)]


    def on_init(self):
        pygame.init()
        self._display_surf = pygame.display.set_mode(self.size, pygame.HWSURFACE | pygame.DOUBLEBUF)
        self._display_surf.fill(BLACK)
        self._running = True

        # Create Score Board
        self.score = 0
        self.displayScore(self.score, 45)

        # Create Initial Food
        self.initFood = Food(RED, 10, 10)
        self._display_surf.blit(self.initFood.image, self.initFood.rect)

        # display the initial Snake array
        for i in range(len(self.snake)):
            self._display_surf.blit(self.snake[i].image, self.snake[i].rect)

        # display the board
        for i in range(len(self.boarder)):
            self._display_surf.blit(self.boarder[i].image, self.boarder[i].rect)

        pygame.display.update()


    """
    Helper Method that will run the events that are clicked on by the user
    """
    def on_event(self):
        # Checks if Snake crashes with itself - LOSE
        for i in range(1, len(self.snake)):
            if pygame.sprite.collide_rect(self.snake[0], self.snake[1]):
                self.spaceToRestartText(20)
                self.gameRestart()
            if pygame.sprite.collide_rect(self.snake[0], self.snake[i]):
                self.spaceToRestartText(20)
                self.gameRestart()

        # Check if Snake hits the boarder - LOSE
        for i in range(len(self.boarder)):
            if pygame.sprite.collide_rect(self.snake[0], self.boarder[i]):
                self.spaceToRestartText(20)
                self.gameRestart()

        # Checks if Snake eats Food 
        if pygame.sprite.collide_rect(self.snake[0], self.initFood):
            self.eatFood()

        # set the direction based of key that is pressed
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                self._running = False
            if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
                    # check for self collision before eating any food - weird collision method error fix
                    if self.move == 'right':
                        self.spaceToRestartText(20)
                        self.gameRestart()
                        break
                    self.move = 'left'

                if event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                    # check for self collision before eating any food
                    if self.move == 'left':
                        self.spaceToRestartText(20)
                        self.gameRestart()
                        break
                    self.move = 'right'

                if event.key == pygame.K_UP:
                    # check for self collision before eating any food
                    if self.move == 'down':
                        self.spaceToRestartText(20)
                        self.gameRestart()
                        break
                    self.move = 'up'

                if event.key == pygame.K_DOWN:
                    # check for self collision before eating any food
                    if self.move == 'up':
                        self.spaceToRestartText(20)
                        self.gameRestart()
                        break
                    self.move = 'down'

        # if stored current direction is right           
        if self.move == 'right':
            print("RIGHT")

            # Reset the Board
            self.boardReset()

            # Store the current head of the snake
            snakeHead = self.snake[0]

            # remove the last block of the snake
            self.snake.pop()

            # create a new head for the snake that is shifted toward the right
            newHead = snakeHead.moveRight()

            # add the newly created head to the front of the list - make head
            self.snake.insert(0, newHead)

            # displays moved snake
            for i in range(len(self.snake)):
                self._display_surf.blit(self.snake[i].image, self.snake[i].rect)
            pygame.display.update()

            pygame.time.delay(timeDelaySpeed)

        # if stored current direction is left
        if self.move == 'left':
            print("LEFT")

            # Reset the Board
            self.boardReset()

            # Store the current head of the snake
            snakeHead = self.snake[0]

            # remove the last block of the snake
            self.snake.pop()

            # create a new head for the snake that is shifted toward the right
            newHead = snakeHead.moveLeft()

            # add the newly created head to the front of the list - make head
            self.snake.insert(0, newHead)

            # displays moved snake
            for i in range(len(self.snake)):
                self._display_surf.blit(self.snake[i].image, self.snake[i].rect)
            pygame.display.update()

            pygame.time.delay(timeDelaySpeed)

        # if stored current direction is up
        if self.move == 'up':
            print("UP")

            # Reset the Board
            self.boardReset()

            # Store the current head of the snake
            snakeHead = self.snake[0]

            # remove the last block of the snake
            self.snake.pop()

            # create a new head for the snake that is shifted toward the right
            newHead = snakeHead.moveUp()

            # add the newly created head to the front of the list - make head
            self.snake.insert(0, newHead)

            # displays moved snake
            for i in range(len(self.snake)):
                self._display_surf.blit(self.snake[i].image, self.snake[i].rect)
            pygame.display.update()

            pygame.time.delay(timeDelaySpeed)

        # if stored current direction is down
        if self.move == 'down':
            print("DOWN")

            # Reset the Board
            self.boardReset()

            # Store the current head of the snake
            snakeHead = self.snake[0]

            # remove the last block of the snake
            self.snake.pop()

            # create a new head for the snake that is shifted toward the right
            newHead = snakeHead.moveDown()

            # add the newly created head to the front of the list - make head
            self.snake.insert(0, newHead)

            # displays moved snake
            for i in range(len(self.snake)):
                self._display_surf.blit(self.snake[i].image, self.snake[i].rect)
            pygame.display.update()

            pygame.time.delay(timeDelaySpeed)


    """
    Helper method that displays the current score on the screen.
    """
    def displayScore(self, score, size):
        font = pygame.font.SysFont("Comic Sans MS", size)
        ScoreBoard = font.render("SCORE: {}".format(score), False, (WHITE))
        self._display_surf.blit(ScoreBoard, [90, 100])
        pygame.display.update()


    """
    Helper method that will reset the screen:

    Make screen Black
    Add the current Food block
    Add the current Score
    """
    def boardReset(self):
        # Erases the current screen
        self._display_surf = pygame.display.set_mode(self.size, pygame.HWSURFACE | pygame.DOUBLEBUF)
        self._display_surf.fill(BLACK)

        # Create Score Board
        self.displayScore(self.score, 45)

        # Add Food
        self._display_surf.blit(self.initFood.image, self.initFood.rect)

        # Add Boarder
        for i in range(len(self.boarder)):
            self._display_surf.blit(self.boarder[i].image, self.boarder[i].rect)


    """
    Eating food helper method
    """
    def eatFood(self):
        # Create a new Food at random location and display it
        self.initFood = Food(RED, 10, 10)
        self._display_surf.blit(self.initFood.image, self.initFood.rect)

        # Create Score Board
        self.score += 1
        self.displayScore(self.score, 45)

        # for i in range(len(self.snake)):
        #     self._display_surf.blit(self.snake[i].image, self.snake[i].rect)
        #
        # Store the last and second to last blocks of the snake
        lastSnakeBlock = self.snake[-1]
        secondToLastBlock = self.snake[-2]

        # if the last two blocks are on the same horizontal line and the last block is to the left of the
        # second to last block, add a block to the left side of the last block
        if lastSnakeBlock.rect.y == secondToLastBlock.rect.y and lastSnakeBlock.rect.x < secondToLastBlock.rect.x:
            newX = lastSnakeBlock.rect.x - 10
            newSnakeBlock = Snake(lastSnakeBlock.color, lastSnakeBlock.width, lastSnakeBlock.height, newX,
                                  lastSnakeBlock.rect.y)
            self.snake.append(newSnakeBlock)

        # if the last two blocks are on the same horizontal line and the last block is to the right of the
        # second to last block, add a block to the right side of the last block
        if lastSnakeBlock.rect.y == secondToLastBlock.rect.y and lastSnakeBlock.rect.x > secondToLastBlock.rect.x:
            newX = lastSnakeBlock.rect.x + 10
            newSnakeBlock = Snake(lastSnakeBlock.color, lastSnakeBlock.width, lastSnakeBlock.height, newX,
                                  lastSnakeBlock.rect.y)
            self.snake.append(newSnakeBlock)

        # if the last two blocks are on the same vertical line and the last block is above the
        # second to last block, add a block above the last block
        if lastSnakeBlock.rect.x == secondToLastBlock.rect.x and lastSnakeBlock.rect.y < secondToLastBlock.rect.y:
            newY = lastSnakeBlock.rect.y - 10
            newSnakeBlock = Snake(lastSnakeBlock.color, lastSnakeBlock.width, lastSnakeBlock.height,
                                  lastSnakeBlock.rect.x, newY)
            self.snake.append(newSnakeBlock)

        # if the last two blocks are on the same vertical line and the last block is below the
        # second to last block, add a block below the last block
        if lastSnakeBlock.rect.x == secondToLastBlock.rect.x and lastSnakeBlock.rect.y > secondToLastBlock.rect.y:
            newY = lastSnakeBlock.rect.y + 10
            newSnakeBlock = Snake(lastSnakeBlock.color, lastSnakeBlock.width, lastSnakeBlock.height,
                                  lastSnakeBlock.rect.x, newY)
            self.snake.append(newSnakeBlock)

        for i in range(len(self.snake)):
            self._display_surf.blit(self.snake[i].image, self.snake[i].rect)


    """
    Takes the player back to initial start state
    """
    def gameRestart(self):
        # Erase the Board
        self._display_surf = pygame.display.set_mode(self.size, pygame.HWSURFACE | pygame.DOUBLEBUF)
        self._display_surf.fill(BLACK)
        self._running = True

        # Recreate the Snake
        self.snake = [Snake(WHITE, 10, 10, 150, 260), Snake(WHITE, 10, 10, 140, 260), Snake(WHITE, 10, 10, 130, 260)]

        # Create Score Board
        self.score = 0
        self.displayScore(self.score, 45)

        # Create Initial Food
        self.initFood = Food(RED, 10, 10)
        self._display_surf.blit(self.initFood.image, self.initFood.rect)

        # set current move to nothing
        self.move = ''

        # draw in the boarder
        for i in range(len(self.boarder)):
            self._display_surf.blit(self.boarder[i].image, self.boarder[i].rect)

        # display the initial Snake array
        for i in range(len(self.snake)):
            self._display_surf.blit(self.snake[i].image, self.snake[i].rect)
        pygame.display.update()


    """
    Creates a List of Blocks that outline the Boarder of the snake game
    """
    def generateBoard(self):
        boardCorners = []
        boardTop = []
        boardSide1 = []
        boardSide2 = []
        boardBottom = []

        # Makes (0,0) of board = (100, 210)
        # top left corner
        boardCorners.append(Snake(CYAN, 10, 10, 90, 200))

        # top right corner
        boardCorners.append(Snake(CYAN, 10, 10, 500, 200))

        # bottom left corner
        boardCorners.append(Snake(CYAN, 10, 10, 90, 610))

        # bottom right corner
        boardCorners.append(Snake(CYAN, 10, 10, 500, 610))

        # top and bottom sides
        topCoord = 100
        for i in range(40):
            boardTop.append(Snake(CYAN, 10, 10, topCoord, 200))
            boardBottom.append(Snake(CYAN, 10, 10, topCoord, 610))
            topCoord += 10

        # sides of board
        sideCoord = 210
        for i in range(40):
            boardSide1.append(Snake(CYAN, 10, 10, 90, sideCoord))
            boardSide2.append(Snake(CYAN, 10, 10, 500, sideCoord))
            sideCoord += 10

        # combine all parts
        allBoarder = boardCorners + boardTop + boardSide1 + boardSide2 + boardBottom

        # return list of blocks
        return allBoarder


    """
    Allows player to restart a game by pressing space bar - displays losing screen
    """
    def spaceToRestartText(self, size):
        self._display_surf = pygame.display.set_mode(self.size, pygame.HWSURFACE | pygame.DOUBLEBUF)
        self._display_surf.fill(BLACK)
        self.youLoseText(50)
        self.yourScoreText(25)
        font = pygame.font.SysFont("Comic Sans MS", size)
        text_surface = font.render("Press space bar to play again", True, WHITE)
        text_rect = text_surface.get_rect(center=(self.weight / 2, self.height / 2))
        self._display_surf.blit(text_surface, text_rect)
        pygame.display.flip()
        done = False
        while not done:
            for event in pygame.event.get():
                if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                    self.running = False
                    done = True
                if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                    if event.key == pygame.K_SPACE:
                        done = True


    """
    Helper function that prints 'YOU LOSE!'
    """
    def youLoseText(self, size):
        font = pygame.font.SysFont("Comic Sans MS", size)
        text_surface = font.render("YOU LOSE!", True, WHITE)
        # Shift height up so no collision with space bar text
        text_rect = text_surface.get_rect(center=(self.weight / 2, (self.height / 2) - 75))
        self._display_surf.blit(text_surface, text_rect)
        pygame.display.flip()


    """
    Helper function that prints your score at loss
    """
    def yourScoreText(self, size):
        font = pygame.font.SysFont("Comic Sans MS", size)
        text_surface = font.render("Your Score was: " + str(self.score), True, WHITE)
        # Shift height up so no collision with space bar text
        text_rect = text_surface.get_rect(center=(self.weight / 2, (self.height / 2) - 35))
        self._display_surf.blit(text_surface, text_rect)
        pygame.display.flip()


    def on_loop(self):
        pass


    def on_render(self):
        pass


    def on_cleanup(self):
        pygame.quit()


    """
    Game Loop
    """
    def on_execute(self):
        if self.on_init() == False:
            self._running = False

        self.move = ''
        while (self._running):
            self.on_event()
            self.on_loop()
            self.on_render()
        self.on_cleanup()


"""
Class to create a Food at a random coordinate
"""

class Food(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self, color, width, height):
        # Call the parent class (Sprite) constructor
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)

        # Create an image of the block, and fill it with a color.
        # This could also be an image loaded from the disk.
        self.image = pygame.Surface([width, height])
        self.image.fill(color)

        # Fetch the rectangle object that has the dimensions of the image
        # Update the position of this object by setting the values of rect.x and rect.y
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()

        # set the position of the Food
        # TODO: change values in randint to use the input width and height
        randX = random.randint(10,49) * 10
        randY = random.randint(21,60) * 10
        self.rect.x = randX
        self.rect.y = randY

class Snake(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    # TODO: Make Snake a chain of Blocks
    def __init__(self, color, width, height, positionX, positionY):
        # Call the parent class (Sprite) constructor
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)

        # Create an image of the block, and fill it with a color.
        # This could also be an image loaded from the disk.
        self.image = pygame.Surface([width, height])
        self.image.fill(color)

        # Fetch the rectangle object that has the dimensions of the image
        # Update the position of this object by setting the values of rect.x and rect.y
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()

        # set the position of the snake
        self.rect.x = positionX
        self.rect.y = positionY

        # set the inputs the usable variables for later code
        self.color = color
        self.width = width
        self.height = height


    """
    Method the will change the direction of the Snake towards the left
    """
    def moveLeft(self):
        newX = self.rect.x - 10
        return Snake(self.color, self.width, self.height, newX, self.rect.y)

    """
    Method that will change the direction of the Snake toward the right
    """
    def moveRight(self):
        newX = self.rect.x + 10
        return Snake(self.color, self.width, self.height, newX, self.rect.y)

    """
    Method that will change the direction of the Snake to go upward
    """
    def moveUp(self):
        newY = self.rect.y - 10
        return Snake(self.color, self.width, self.height, self.rect.x, newY)

    """
    Method that will change the direction of the Snake to go downward
    """
    def moveDown(self):
        newY = self.rect.y + 10
        return Snake(self.color, self.width, self.height, self.rect.x, newY)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    theApp = App()
    theApp.on_execute()
```

[image]

Comment: It works as expected for me. How are you running it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can agree with the answers above. The only problem appears to be that you did not set the FPS i.e. clock.tick(fps) and the game is too fast so it is unplayable. 30 and under will do in my opinion. Please provide more details.

Comment: I just added a screenshot of what I am seeing. I cannot even see the speed because the game won't load up

Comment: Yes, I see, which version are you using?

Comment: Python version? I am using python3. And its says pygame 1.9.6 so I assume that?

Comment: Yes, I omitted python. Have you tried to follow these steps:
[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52718921/problems-getting-pygame-to-show-anything-but-a-blank-screen-on-macos-mojave]
It looks like a dependency issue to me. Not sure

Comment: perfect! yes that worked! Do you know if it launches two windows at once for you?

Comment: Nice, glad to hear that. No, it works like it should, but I am on Windows so...
And I've noticed that when you move down or up and then press the opposite (up or down) the "lose" window appears. So you may look into that as well

Comment: Awesome will look into it! Thanks for you help

Answer (score 0):

Code is okay, worked on my machine.
Can u add a screenshot of your command prompt?

Comment: Hi! I just added a screenshot onto the main post containing what I see. I deleted the print statement that was printing all of the numbers in "on_event"