# Pygame Sprite unresponsive, mac

Tags: python, python-3.x, if-statement, pygame, sprite

First time building a game in [python](/questions/tagged/python), let alone [pygame](/questions/tagged/pygame). When I launch the code the window with the desired BG comes up, and my `Sprite` loads where I want. However, the `Sprite` doesn't move despite all efforts. I've scoured this site and other for resolutions but to no avail.

Note: I am using an upgraded mid-2009 mac book with OS X 10.11.6 and I am launching the code via terminal (python boss_fight.py). Also, I downloaded[tag: pygame] via homebrew.

Other things I've tried:

1. `elif` then `if` vs. `if` then `if` statements
2. Adding `print` functions after if statements regarding key input to see if the input is registered, does not `print`.
3. List item adding `print` functions after `if` statements regarding key input to see if input is registered, does not `print`.
4. Updating [pygame](/questions/tagged/pygame)
5. Updating [python](/questions/tagged/python)
6. Launching with command pythonw boss_fight.py (this yields: ImportError: No module named pygame) which is weird because running the prompt python boss_fight.py runs the game.
7. I've tried a few other things but can't remember them all

Here's the code:

```py
import pygame  # load pygame keywords
import sys     # let  python use your file system
import os      # help python identify your OS

class Player(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    
    # Spawn a player
    
    def __init__(self):
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
        self.movex = 0
        self.movey = 0
        self.frame = 0
        self.images = []
        img = pygame.image.load(os.path.join('images','hero.png'))
        self.images.append(img)
        self.image = self.images[0]
        self.rect  = self.image.get_rect()

    def control(self,x,y):
        
        # control player movement
        
        self.movex += x
        self.movey += y

    def update(self):
        
        # Update sprite position
        

        self.rect.x = self.rect.x + self.movex
        self.rect.y = self.rect.y + self.movey

        # moving left
        if self.movex < 0:
            self.frame += 1
            if self.frame > 3 * ani:
                self.frame = 0
            self.image = self.images[self.frame//ani]

        # moving right
        if self.movex > 0:
            self.frame += 1
            if self.frame > 3 * ani:
                self.frame = 0
            self.image = self.images[(self.frame//ani)+4]



# Setup

worldx = 960
worldy = 720

fps = 40        # frame rate
ani = 4        # animation cycles
clock = pygame.time.Clock()
pygame.init()
main = True

BLUE  = (25,25,200)
BLACK = (23,23,23 )
WHITE = (254,254,254)
ALPHA = (0,255,0)

world = pygame.display.set_mode([worldx,worldy])
backdrop = pygame.image.load(os.path.join('images','stage.jpeg')).convert()
backdropbox = world.get_rect()
player = Player()   # spawn player
player.rect.x = 0
player.rect.y = 0
player_list = pygame.sprite.Group()
player_list.add(player)
steps = 10      # how fast to move


# Main loop

while main:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            pygame.quit(); sys.exit()
            main = False

        elif event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
                player.control(-steps,0)
                print('left')
            
            elif event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT: 
                player.control(steps,0)
                print('right')

            elif event.key == pygame.K_UP:
                print('up')

        elif event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
            if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
                player.control(steps,0)

            elif event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT: 
                player.control(-steps,0)

            elif event.key == pygame.K_q:
                pygame.quit()
                sys.exit()
                main = False

    world.blit(backdrop, backdropbox)
    player.update()
    player_list.draw(world)
    pygame.display.update()
    clock.tick(fps)
```

Comment: Try upgrading your PyGame version according to https://stackoverflow.com/a/61766668/51685 – this fixed things on my macOS 10.15 machine.

Comment: Beyond that, your `self.images` array only has one item, so comment out those lines changing `self.image`, or your program will also crash.

Comment: Upgrading pygame worked. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The place where I think you've mistaken is where you're writing code for update

The way I do it is

```
def update(self):
        
        # Update sprite position
        

        self.rect.x = self.rect.x + self.movex
        self.rect.y = self.rect.y + self.movey

        # moving left
        if self.movex < 0:
            self.frame += 1
            if self.frame > 3 * ani:
                self.frame = 0
            self.image = self.images[self.frame//ani]

        # moving right
        elif self.movex > 0:
            self.frame += 1
            if self.frame > 3 * ani:
                self.frame = 0
            self.image = self.images[(self.frame//ani)+4]
        self.rect.topleft = self.rect.x, self.rect.y
```

Comment: Thanks for the feedback I will look over this further! However, I updated pygame to 2.0.0 and I now have control. Yay!